# Wordpress auto delete a custom meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

Lets say I have a custom meta field called "debut" and I want after x amount of days(Ex 30 days) it to be deleted from the post/db but the post is still to remain intact just without the value of "debut". How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple plugin that hooks to the loaded state of wordpress and just delete the post meta that meet your criterias...

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'cleanup_expired_meta');

function cleanup_expired_meta(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->execute('DELETE FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts_meta WHERE [conditions]');
}
```

Not tested, just got that off the top of my head, becareful what you do with that, can be dangerous and delete all your post metas... :)

---

That would be the full request, note tho, there are no dates when a META was added. So i'm taking the last modified date of the post. But if a user modifies the post then the meta won't be deleted before another 30 days.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS releasedate ON releasedate.post_id = wp_posts.id AND releasedate.meta_key = "release-date"
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = "Debut" 
AND DATE_ADD(releasedate.meta_value, INTERVAL 30 DAY) < NOW()
```

Note, i'm not sure this will work since the data type of meta_value is a varchar, but if the conversion works, maybe it will not throw off errors.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response, I have 2 follow up questions. How would I set the "debut" tag to be expired after the 30 days and also where would I insert the "debut" tag in the code you just supplied?

Comment: I have another custom field called "release-date" that I could use as the date of reference so I would use that instead of the modified date. With "release-date" value being used instead of modified date i'm thinking the code would look like this?

Comment: { SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = "Debut" 
AND DATE_ADD(wp_posts.post_releat-date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) < NOW()}

Comment: If release date is a meta, then you need to add another LEFT JOIN on wp_postmeta to get the release-date and compare to it. it's a little more tricky...

Comment: how exactly would I achieve the comparison?

Comment: I currently new to php, I've copied the example but i'm getting syntax  errors. i placed it into the functions.php file

Comment: It will take you a programmer beside you to get this working then, i can't do it from afar like that. You'll have to find a way to get it done yourself or get a subcontractant to do the job for you. sorry